What are the `al:` properties in meta tag for?
In this page https://www.facebook.com/groups/562933844569060/ there are these <meta> properties:
al:android:app_name
al:android:package
al:android:url
al:ios:app_name
al:ios:app_store_id
al:ios:url

I get that these are for mobile apps, but do you know where the documentation for the al properties is?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/metadata-reference/

@RichardB has already shared the rightful resource to understand it. If you ever noticed, you opened a website and you have app of that site in your phone then that website is automatically redirected you to the app. This called deeplinking, it takes you to the similar page in the app to serve you the best mobile experience.

Thanks. If you write an answer I'll accept
